# How can I set Date programmatically on Date Picker? setDate is not working?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, datepicker, uidatepicker

I am using Xcode 4.

I have DatePicker Component.

It is taking the Default date which is set in IB's Date 
to highlight and select the date...

I want to set the current date in date picker to be selected...

Not working setDate Method...

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];   

        [ddlDatePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];

        NSLog(@"-%@-",[NSDate date]);
     //NSLog is showing me the current date..Today's Date...
    //But ddlDatePicker is setted to the date on the day on which I created the date 
//Picker...Or You can say date field in the DatePicker's IB Properties.. 

    ![enter image description here][1]
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Also let us know if you see any related warnings perhaps - thanks.

Comment: might be your date is in invalid formate

Comment: Does `NSLog(@"%@", PickerView);` produce `(null)`?

Comment: It is producing null in view will appear but not in view didload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not connected with `outlet` your `ddlDatePicker`, so you haven't got reference to that object and couldn't manage it.

Open IB and connect this `UIDatePicker` with your variable in appropriate controller.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in viewWillAppear rather than viewDidLoad. Also, ensure ddlDatePicker is not nil:

```
NSLog(@"%@", ddlDatePicker);
```

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", ddlDatePicker);
IT IS SHOWING ME THE CURRENT DATE

Comment: BUT WHAT SHOULD I DO NOW...CAN T GETTING

Comment: Again 
I am sorry  NSLog(@"%@", ddlDatePicker);
is also showing null in didLoad also...